# ls sorted from right to left

Tags: bash, ls

Example list sorted from left to right.

```
DATA2
DATA4
FILE1
FILE3
```

Example list sorted from right to left.

```
FILE1
DATA2
FILE3
DATA4
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
cat file | rev | sort | rev
```

Where file contains the content needing to be sorted.

```
$ cat file

DATA2
DATA4
FILE1
FILE3
```

Output:

```
$ cat file | rev | sort | rev

FILE1
DATA2
FILE3
DATA4
```

All it does is reverse each line before applying sort, then reverses each line back again.

Comment: I see your title says "ls", if so, just replace `cat file` with `ls`

Comment: +1 Did not know about `rev`. I have used bash on and off since 1992 and I still learn about new commands regularly.